# Ignoring multiple variables with numpy (function included)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Currently I'm using the following to successfully ignore a single variable

```
nValues = np.asarray(values, dtype="|S8")
mask = nValues != 'NA'
```

However, I am trying to ignore more than one variable so I tried:

```
nValues = np.asarray(values, dtype="|S8")
mask = nValues != 'NA'
mask = nValues != '0.00'
```

and

```
nValues = np.asarray(values, dtype="|S8")
mask = nValues != 'NA' or '0.00'
```

and

```
nValues = np.asarray(values, dtype="|S8")
mask = nValues != 'NA'
mask = nValues[mask] != '0.00'
```

Unfortunately I can't get it working, any ideas?

The full function is:

```
def mapValues(values):
    nValues = np.asarray(values, dtype="|S8")
    mask = nValues != 'CFNA'
    maskedValues = [float(i.split('%')[0]) for i in nValues[mask]]
    colorMap = np.array(['#F8696B', '#F86E6C', '#F8736D', '#F8786E', '#F97E6F', '#F98370', '#F98871', '#FA8E72', '#FA9373', '#FA9874', '#FA9E75', '#FBA376', '#FBA877', '#FBAD78', '#FCB379', '#FCB87A', '#FCBD7B', '#FCC37C', '#FDC87D', '#FDCD7E', '#FDD37F', '#FED880', '#FEDD81', '#FEE382', '#FEE883', '#FCEB84', '#F6E984', '#F0E784', '#E9E583', '#E3E383', '#DCE182', '#D6E082', '#D0DE82', '#C9DC81', '#C3DA81', '#BDD881', '#B6D680', '#B0D580', '#AAD380', '#A3D17F', '#9DCF7F', '#96CD7E', '#90CB7E', '#8ACA7E', '#83C87D', '#7DC67D', '#77C47D', '#70C27C', '#6AC07C', '#63BE7B'])
    _, bins = np.histogram(maskedValues, 49)
    mapped = np.digitize(maskedValues, bins)
    nValues[mask] = colorMap[mapped - 1]
    nValues[~mask] = "#808080"
    return nValues.tolist()
```

Comment: Saying `I can't get it working` is nearly as bad as giving the error message without noting which line triggered it.  Of if there isn't an error message, say what is wrong with the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's look at what you're doing wrong:

```
mask = nValues != 'NA'
mask = nValues != '0.00'
```

It really helps to print out `mask` after each version to see if it's anything reasonable. Given `values = ['NA', '0.00', '1.11']`, you obviously want to get `[False, False, True]`. What do you get?

```
array([True, False, True])
```

Why? Well, you've just assigned `mask` to one mask array, then immediately forgotten that and reassigned `mask` to a *different* mask array. That can't possibly do anything useful, or anything different than the second line on its own. And indeed you are getting a mask array for all elements that are not `'0.00'`, whether or not they're `'NA'`.

---

Next, you try this:

```
mask = nValues != 'NA' or '0.00'
```

That doesn't do what you want, and it's hard to imagine how it could. No matter how you expect precedence to work in Python, this will ultimately have to be the same as either `(nValues != 'NA') or '0.00'`, or `nValues != ('NA' or '0.00')`. Try typing those two expressions into the command-line interpreter to see what they each do. One gives you a `ValueError` because you're trying to `or` a mask array with `0.00`, the other successfully masks `'NA'`, ignoring `'0.00'`, because `('NA' or '0.00')` is the same thing as `'NA'`. Neither one is what you want.

---

To make that sensible, you'd need to do this:

```
mask = (nValues != 'NA') or (nValues != '0.00')
```

However, that still doesn't work. Again, you get a `ValueError`, this time because you're trying to `or` together two arrays. The error description "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous" tells you what's going wrong: `or` always wants to treat its operands as truth values. It returns the first value if it's truthy, the second value otherwise. You can't use it to elementwise `or` together two arrays.

---

To do that, you need the `|` operator. So:

```
mask = (nValues != 'NA') | (nValues != '0.00')
```

And now it sort of "works"… but it doesn't do the right thing. You get a mask array, but it's `[True, True, True]`!

Why? Well, every value that you can possibly imagine is either not `'NA'`, or not `'0.00'`, right?

---

You wanted an *and* here, not an *or*. So:

```
mask = (nValues != 'NA') & (nValues != '0.00')
```

Comment: Fantastic explanations, very detailed responses. (Psst: You missed a single quote on the last two `0.00` values)

Comment: @Hyflex: Thanks for catching the typos!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
mask = (nValues != 'NA') & (nValues != '0.00')
```

Comment: are you sure?  you are being moderated down because your answer wasn't implicitly correct, nor came with any explanation

Comment: If I understand the question, this _does_ answer it. However, it really should explain what it does if it's this unobvious to everyone…

Comment: It 100% solves my problem, hence why I market it as the answer.

Comment: @Hyflex: Do you understand _why_ it solves your problem? If so, then it probably doesn't matter as much than NewAlexandria and Drew don't. But if you don't understand it either, then it's not sufficient.

Comment: @abarnet after printing my output post-change I was able to see what it was doing so yes. I did understand it however. I'll change my answer to your reply as it could help the community.

Comment: @Hyflex: I'd at least upvote this one if I were you, even if I didn't accept it. (I already upvoted it.) After all, it's a good answer, and the first good answer, and it was exactly what you needed to figure everything out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.in1d()` to test for an arbitrary number of values to exclude:

```
vars = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, 20).astype('|S8')
print vars
# ['8' '0' '2' '1' '2' '3' '1' '1' '0' '9' '8' '6' '10' '0' '9' '9' '3' '9'
#  '6' '1']

exclude = np.array([1, 2, 3, 5, 7], dtype='|S8')
mask = ~np.in1d(vars, exclude)

print vars[mask]
# ['8' '0' '0' '9' '8' '6' '10' '0' '9' '9' '9' '6']

print vars[~mask]
# ['2' '1' '2' '3' '1' '1' '3' '1']
```